# How to handle the connection event of widget output in Orange3?

Tags: python, orange

I am developing an add-on widget for Orange3. Is there any way to handle the event of connection/disconnection of widget output?

I would like to postpone heavy calculations for one of the outputs until this output is connected with the input of another widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no signal (Orange3 employs PyQt's signals & slots) in source widget about it being connected with another one.

But you can always postpone heavy computation by hiding it in lazy properties or starting this computation within the receiving widget.

```py
class TargetWidget(OWWidget): 
   @Inputs.obj
   def set_obj(self, obj): 
       # start computation here
       obj.compute()
```